# MySQL - "select" speed

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I was wondering if it's faster to select all fields from a table like:

```
SELECT *
```

or select just the ones you really need:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5...
```

assuming the table has around 10 fields, and I only need like 5 or 6 for this operation

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the reason not to use select * ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wherever possible, it's faster to select precise fields.   Your intuition is correct:  anything you can conceptualize as wasted machine time is likely indeed wasted work, though the magnitude is always subject to question.  This particular example is one reason generated code (through [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)) is so popular!  With ORM, most basic and repetitive optimization stuff is in the hands of the ORM itself, and custom hand-written queries are the exception rather than the rule.

Answer (score 3):

You should always select the exact fields, or else you could face enormous performance hits when you modify your table. Think about what would happen if you decide to add a blob to that table. You might accidentally select megabytes of unneeded data.

There is a slight nuance. It might be better for the query cache to have only a limited number of queries, so when you sometimes need only field1, 2 and 3, and some other times you may need 4 as well and 4 is only a small field, it might be better to always select 1, 2, 3 and 4, even if you need only the first 3. You still should *never* use `*` though.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing your fields can have big impacts on speed. When you do a select * and some of the fields are BLOB or TEXT you will big negative impacts. Check [this documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/blob.html) and serach 'avoid using select *'.